# CosmosDB SQL Api not persisting Enum values 0

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, asp.net-core-5.0

**Problem:**

I am working on a .NET Core 5.0 web app that is using Cosmos DB as my persistence store and it does not seem to be persisting enums when they are set to 0 (default value). In the code below, when I create a session, the default SessionStatus value is Planned. If I set the Session to InProgress or Completed. It shows up in the database with a value of 1 or 2 respectively.

**My Code**
Session Class

```
public class Session
{
    [JsonProperty("creator_id")]
    public string CreatorId { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty("session_status")]
    public SessionStatus SessionStatus { get; private set; }
}
public enum SessionStatus
{
    Planned,
    InProgress,
    Completed
}
```

Repo:

```
var document = await cosmosDbClient.CreateDocumentAsync(session);
```

CosmosClient:

```
public async Task<Document> CreateDocumentAsync(object document, RequestOptions options = null,
    bool disableAutomaticIdGeneration = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return await _documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(
        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName), document, options,
        disableAutomaticIdGeneration, cancellationToken);
}
```

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried setting enum json converted on the Enum object to store as a string in db, but same behavior for session_status in db.
2. I could set the default value for SessionStatus to 1 as a work around, but would rather understand the underyling issue.

Comment: Sounds like the JSON serializer you are using is set to ignore default values. You could check the options there or if you only want to set it solely for this property add the attribute `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]`.

Comment: That did the trick!! No idea why it wouldn't be set to include in the first place....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the underlying JSON serializer that is used is set to ignore default values. The behaviour can be specified in the options when creating a client to the cosmos database, but can also be scoped to individual parameters using the JSON annotations.

Cosmos v2 & v3 by default use the serializer package `Newtonsoft.Json`, where you can use `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]` on an individual parameter to always write it.

Cosmos v4 uses `System.Text.Json` by default where you can do the same using `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never)]`.

The reason to not include it would be that reading & writing the default value to your CosmosDB consumes a little extra `RU` and might not be needed as it gets deserialized to its default value anyway when working with a class model.